# Really tricky need to find the answer. Hit me up with ideas

Tags: riddle

One must answer riddles three
Your quest has truly just begun
Try these answers all as one

> 1. What is yours?
> 2. What paddles swiftly?
> 3. What is a safe place?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!  It's a bit unclear what you're looking for - where are these questions from, and what sort of answers do you expect?  (And consider taking [the tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to earn your first badge!)

Comment: It's for a roblox event, in order to move to the next step you have to answer that riddle with one word that fits all of those requirements.

Comment: i see u tryin to get that crystal key >:o

Comment: (I have converted a couple of answers-that-aren't-actually-answers to comments.)

Comment: Is this, as Thomas J says, a question from some sort of ongoing competition?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Uh...if you count roblox the game as a competition ;)

Comment: @NL628 The *game* isn't a competition. But *specific things within it* might be. I don't know enough about Roblox to know how plausible that is.

Answer (score 1):

It is

> nothing.

As to assume when you say "What is yours?" Well obviously,

> nothing is yours.

When you say "What paddles swiftly?" That is when I say

> nothing again because there is no source of what paddles swiftly.

When you say "What is a safe place?" I say

> nothing again. Because nowhere is a safe place. So nothing at all is a safe place.